# After creation of custom shipping method the getShippingCarrier() function returns nothing why?

Tags: magento

I followed this guide:

```
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module
```

and created a custom shipping method.
But as I call this function:

```
getShippingCarrier() from the Mage_Sales_Model_Order  (collection Sales/Order)
```

on the orders created with my custom shipping method, I get nothing. 
Cannot figure out why this happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same problem here.

It solved my problem (https://www.facebook.com/scandiweb/posts/788413034530650):

It´s an interesting limitation in Magento. Namely – when creating new shipping method don’t use underscores in carrier or method code. Underscore in code has potential to break any code that uses this method – `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::getShippingMethod`. As an example I found out myself – I was missing shipping carrier in exported orders for certain shipping methods. Not cool at all if this happens live.
The reason lies here in `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::getShippingMethod`

```
public function getShippingMethod($asObject = false)
{
  $shippingMethod = parent::getShippingMethod();
  if (!$asObject) {
    return $shippingMethod;
  } else {
    list($carrierCode, $method) = explode('_', $shippingMethod, 2);
    return new Varien_Object(array(
      'carrier_code' => $carrierCode,
      'method' => $method
    ));
  }
}
```

Notice the explode function call. It takes string that looks something like ‘carriercode_methodcode’ and splits into parts by underscore. If however there are some additional underscores like in ‘carrier_code_method_code’ it will get wrong codes and for example `getShippingCarrier()` will fail to return carrier that was used on order.

Comment: Incredible, this was really the issue. This is very ugly because it's a little stupid to explode a string by underscore because underscore is a common character used in strings. I saw a lot of third party modules that are using underscore in carrier codes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you but for different reasons. What I notice in the guide you refered to was this code was missing from the config.xml file

```
<default>
    <carriers>
        <saturdaydelivery>
            <active>1</active>
            <model>saturdaydelivery/carrier_saturdaydelivery</model>
            <title>Saturday Delivery</title>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
            <sallowspecific>0</sallowspecific>
        </saturdaydelivery>
    </carriers>
</default>
```

It would go outside the `<globals>...<\globals>` element, after it I suppose (I have it as the last code before `</config>` but I have no idea if that matters). The `<model>` tag is the important one in this case as that's what the `getShippingCarrier()` function goes looking for.

BTW, "saturdaydelivery" was what I had instead of "newmodule" as described in the guide. (In case it wasn't obvious! ;) )